Finding the indices of continuous 0 from a sequence of 0 and 1
Let say I have a sequence of 0 and 1 as below example
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]

We can think this sequence as a sequence of continuous 0 but interrupted by 1.
My goal is to fetch the indices where sequence of continuous 0 interrupted by 1. Therefore in this example, I should get
0, 7, 9, 11

For below sequence
[1,1,1,1,0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

I should get 4, 8
For [0,0,0,0,0,0] I should get 0
For [1,1,1,1] I should get NULL
Is there any Python method/function to directly achieve this?

Your examples seem to show "a sequence of continuous 1 interrupted by 0", not the other way around

this seems like homework: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Using numpy may be an overkill, but it's easy to make such operations with it:
import numpy as np

input_data = [1,1,1,1,0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
np.where(np.diff([1] + input_data + [1]) == -1)

yields the outputs you want.
It works by calculating a difference between each pair of consecutive numbers and returning indices where there is a 1 -> 0 transition.

Given, that you examples actually show "a sequence of continuous 1 interrupted by 0", here's the code that will work for you. Basically you iterate over the sequence using enumerate, which provides an index of iteration, then do the checks if the element by that index is something you look for, and the previous element is different.
def interrupt_indices(seq, interrupter=0):
    return [i for (i, e) in enumerate(seq) if e == interrupter and (i == 0 or seq[i-1] != interrupter)]
    
print(interrupt_indices([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1])) # [0, 7, 9, 11]
print(interrupt_indices([1,1,1,1,0, 0, 0, 1, 0]))         # [4, 8]
print(interrupt_indices([0,0,0,0,0,0]))                   # [0]
print(interrupt_indices([1,1,1,1]))                       # []
print(interrupt_indices([]))                              # []


You can replace the default value of interrupter with 1, to get the logic that you originally described in your post

data = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]
find_continuous_sequence = lambda data: [i for i,v in enumerate(data) if v==0 and data[i]!=data[i-1]]
output = find_continuous_sequence(data)

Output:
0, 7, 9, 11


A little bit of explanation why and how this works, perhaps? The best answers contain an explanation and the code implementing it.
